# CSS animation moves second element down during animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, ng-animate, animate.css

I have a problem when animating `ng-if` with `ngAnimate`. I have two different containers which replace each other, by fadeInLeft the new element and fadeOutRight the old element. However, during the animation the second container is moved down.

Here is a simplified example of my problem (display in full-screen mode to see the exact problem):

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.show = true;
  
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
    }, 3000);
  
  
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
}

.box.ng-enter {
  animation: fadeInLeft 1.0s;
}

.box.ng-leave {
  animation: fadeOutRight 1.0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.css" />

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-if="show" class="box" style="background:red"></div>
  <div ng-if="!show" class="box" style="background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the default behavior of `<div>` block level elements to occupy their own space. You can add `position: absolute` to the box class so that it comes out of the normal document flow.

Also add `width: 100%` since the width of the absolutely positioned div is limited to the content.

In order to limit the positioning inside this area, make sure you add `position: relative` to the parent element.

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSR7UrZ95DfFqQ9iX0De?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.show = true;

  $interval(function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  }, 3000);


});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.box.ng-enter {
  animation: fadeInLeft 1.0s;
}
.box.ng-leave {
  animation: fadeOutRight 1.0s;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.css" />

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-if="show" class="box" style="background:red"></div>
  <div ng-if="!show" class="box" style="background:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But with your solution I still have the problem when I add content to the animated `div` and the fadeOutRight animation is not shown. [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3DoSKhGbqqlVImkT3b3Y?p=preview)

Comment: Can we do this without position absolute, it kind make things meaningless